# Trying to display text from mysql field starting 30 words into paragraph?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure this out for the life of me... Using wordpress trying to display excerpt from posts starting 30 words in.. php mysql

Please help!

Comment: How many words do you want after the 30 start point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best solution, but it is a start. Get  your post into a variable (`$str` in this case ), and then just remove the first 30 words:

```
$str = preg_replace( "/(([^ ]* ){30})/", '', $str );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $original), 30));
```

Convert to array using a space as a seperator.  Select starting at array index 30. Convert back to string.